# Join and Group by Clause gives wrong output

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have two table L with columns (Code, Qtr, Fy, Limit) and R with (Code, Qtr,Fy,Limit). I want to get sum of limit of left and right table group by code, Qtr an Fy

The following query runs with no error but gives wrong output, can anyone help me in getting right output. IF I use only one table it works fine. I guess problem is with join

```
select L.Code, L. Qtr, L.FY, sum(L.limit),sum(R.Limit) 
from tbl L,tbl R Where
L.Code=R.Code AND
L.Qtr=R.Qtr AND
L.FY=R.FY
group by L.Code,L.Qtr,L.FY
```

Sample Data ( the table contains other column as well but here i m keeping only selected)

```
Tbl L                                        
Code    Qtr,   Fy   Limit                    
001      1      70    200                     
001      1      70    700                     
001       2     70    500    
001       2     70    300

Table R

Code     Qtr    Fy    Limit

001      1       70    1000

001      1       70    200

001      2       70    50

001      2       70    125


Result

Code   Qtr    Fy  Sum(l.Limit)    sum(R.Limit)

001     1     70   900               1200

001     2     70   800               175
```

I m Using Mysql

Comment: What are you using? Sql server or Mysql? What output you are expecting?

Comment: Can you post some sample data? Also what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select code, qtr, fy, sum(lsum), sum(rsum)
from (
select L.Code, L.Qtr, L.FY, L.limit as lsum, 0 as rsum
from L
union all
select R.Code, R.Qtr, R.FY, 0 as lsum, R.limit as rsum
from R) as combined
group by code, qtr, fy
```

Using `join` in this case would be a wrong idea because it will create multiple records (one for each match between L and R) and then when you do a `sum` you get incorrect results.

Comment: When did Ajit told that he wanted sum from both tables in one column?

Comment: no i cannot do that as i have to make is separate. Moreover; problem is same, result is more than actual value, actually it doubles the amount so i guess problem is with join

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed the join - specifically, you're running into problems because you are using a `GROUP BY` *after* the join, when the join criteria results in non-unique rows.  Usually, the way to solve this is to group **before** the join:

```
SELECT L.code, L.qtr, L.fy, L.lim as L_lim, R.lim as R_lim
FROM (SELECT code, qtr, fy, SUM(lim) as lim
      FROM L
      GROUP BY code, qtr, fy) L
JOIN (SELECT code, qtr, fy, SUM(lim) as lim
      FROM R
      GROUP BY code, qtr, fy) R
  ON R.code = L.code
     AND R.qtr = L.qtr
     AND R.fy = L.fy
```

(have a [working SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8217/2))

Note that this will only show results for rows that are in both tables.  Also, `LIMIT` is a reserved word (in MySQL and some other RDBMSs), so you're better off avoiding that for a column name.

Comment: Thank you !!     This should also work but i used previous method